# CSS layout when resize

Tags: html, css, layout, resize, border

I have the following code:

```css
body {
 /* Background */
 width: 900px;
 height: 900px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 
 /* Font */
 font-family: "arial";
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "stylesheet.css">
  <meta name = "author" content = "Afik Atashga" />
  <meta name = "description" content = "Website" />
  <meta name = "keywords" content = "Website, Afik Atashga" />
  <meta http-equiv = "Content-Type" content = "text/html; charset = UTF-8" />
  <title>Website.</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
 </body>
</html>


/* HTML Tags */ 
html {
 direction: ltr;
 background-color: #ededed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

When I resize the window, the content is out of the border.
How can I keep the change relative so it won't leave the border?

Comment: set height: auto;

Comment: Don't work @IvinRaj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `width: 100%` in combination with `max-width: 900px;`. This way, your `body` will not become larger than `900px`, but will adapt to a viewport size smaller than `900px`.

Also use `box-sizing: border-box;` - this will include the border width into your specified width. That way, your element will not become larger than specified. I would recommend to [read about the CSS box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model).

```css
body {
  /* Background */
  width: 100%; /* <-- adapt to viewport width */
  max-width: 900px; /* <-- width not larger than 900px */
  height: 900px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* <-- include border into width declaration */
  margin: 0 auto; /* <-- center body */
  /* Font */
  font-family: "arial";
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
```

See [MDN about `max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/max-width) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, but when i increased in 10% (110%) it leave the borders @andreas

Comment: Why would you do that? Leaving the border on 110% is a totally correct behaviour...

Comment: But in others sites no matter how i increase, the text is in the borders and won't leave it. There is no way to keep it in the border in any percent? @andreas

Comment: Can you give us an image of the actual problem? I think we don't understand each other O:) If you want any width, just remove the `max-width` rule. That way, your body will always be as wide as the viewport.

Comment: Ah ok, this happens only, because you don't have spaces in your text! Given that, the browser has no clue where to break your long single word! You can use `word-wrap: break-word;` to break the word inside.

Comment: I thought about it, but i wonder if theres an option to not use it.. I mean that the size of the font and the border will increase / dis increase at the same size. I mean when i increase the size to 110%, so the font will grow to fit right in.. There is an option like this? @andreas

Comment: There isn't really an option for that, for you never know, how much horizontal space your font will take...

Comment: OK, Thanks. @andreas

Comment: You're welcom. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to this css:

```
          body {
          /* Background */
          max-width: 900px;
          width: 100%;
          height: 900px;
          border: 1px solid black;
          /* Font */
          font-family: "arial";
          font-size: 12px;
          color: #000000;
      }
```

Comment: First of all thanks, i did it but it still don't work. It keep it relative only when the increment / decrement of the resize is 25%, when it's 10% for example, it out of the border

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
 /* Background */
 width: 100%;
 height: 900px;
  max-width:900px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 
 /* Font */
 font-family: "arial";
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "stylesheet.css">
  <meta name = "author" content = "Afik Atashga" />
  <meta name = "description" content = "Website" />
  <meta name = "keywords" content = "Website, Afik Atashga" />
  <meta http-equiv = "Content-Type" content = "text/html; charset = UTF-8" />
  <title>Website.</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
 </body>
</html>


/* HTML Tags */ 
html {
 direction: ltr;
 background-color: #ededed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Typo: `width: 100%px;`

Comment: Sorry width:100%;@andreas